# ProtoBuf-Net to do raw read

Tags: .net, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I want to have a simple piece of code that will iterate through a random stream of protocol buffers, and print out the contents without having an explicit understanding of the structural contents.  Something that is equivalent to XmlReader.Read() inside a while loop

```
using (ProtoBuf.ProtoReader protoReader = 
      new ProtoBuf.ProtoReader(stream1, null, 
            new ProtoBuf.SerializationContext { }))
{
    protoReader.ReadFieldHeader();
    while (protoReader.WireType != ProtoBuf.WireType.None)
    {
       switch (protoReader.WireType)
       {
       case ProtoBuf.WireType.Fixed64:
           Console.WriteLine(protoReader.ReadInt64());
           break;
       case ProtoBuf.WireType.Fixed32:
           Console.WriteLine(protoReader.ReadInt32());
           break;
       case ProtoBuf.WireType.StartGroup:
           Console.WriteLine(protoReader.ReadInt32());
           break;
       default:
           Console.WriteLine(protoReader.WireType);
           break;
       }
    }
}
```

However I don't know how to advance the protocol buffer to the next element.  In my test, it keeps returning "StartGroup" and never advancing.  How can I advance to the next element in the stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ReadFieldHeader()` should be inside the loop:

```
while(protoReader.ReadFieldHeader() > 0)
{
    //...
}
```

Note: if you don't know how to process a given field, there is a `.SkipField()` method that will *correctly* read the data - for example:

```
default:
    Console.WriteLine(protoReader.WireType);
    protoReader.SkipField();
    break;
```

you must read or skip the data exactly once per field-header.

In the case of groups and sub-items, you need to use `StartSubItem` etc:

```
var tok = ProtoReader.StartSubItem(protoReader);
// an inner while-loop, etc
ProtoReader.EndSubItem(tok);
```

alternatively: use `SkipField()`.